# Split numpy array into sub-arrays based on conditions

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of daily values and time steps:

```
A = [[ 0.1   0.05  0.05  0.05  0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1 .......]]

T = [['19730101' '19730102' '19730103' '19730104' '19730105' '19730106' ....... '19931231']]
```

and want to split `A` into sub-arrays for each month such as:

```
s = numpy.split(A,condition) # condition is when there is a change in month index in T
```

I am not clear on how to track change in index of monthly digits. Any suggestions would be appreciative.

Comment: the value of T is changing or its increasing???

Comment: Increasing for a single month (in terms of days) but changing for years and remain in same format `%y4%m2%d2` such as `19730101`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it.
There is probably a faster/neater way to do it with numpy, but I think this is pretty straight-forward.

```
A = [0.1,   0.05,  0.05,  0.05,  0.1,   0.1,   0.1]
T = ['19730101', '19730102', '19730103', '19730104', '19730105', '19730106', '19931231']

combined = zip(A, T)
combined = sorted(combined, key=lambda x: x[1]) # Sort on timestamp

splits = []
current_month = None
for a, t in combined:
    month = t[4:6]
    print month
    if not month == current_month:
        splits.append([a,]) # Add new split
        current_month = month
    else:
        splits[-1].append(a) # Add to current split
print splits
```

Comment: It is still single array. No split

Comment: I forgot to change `current_month` when the month changes. It works now, as long as A and T are one dimensional arrays of the same length.

Comment: weird, still single array

Comment: See updated code with your example data. Note that since your original data was not valif Pythin code, I have converted A and T to one dimensional lists.

Comment: Also, I guess instead of checking just for month you want the year+month concatenation? Currently '197310' and '197410' would end up in the same list. In that case change `month=t[4:6]` to `yearmonth=t[:6]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it quite easily using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html):

```
>>> T = ['20140101', '20140102', '20140201', '20140202']
>>> A = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
>>> s = pandas.Series(A, T)
>>> groups = s.groupby(lambda i: i[:6])
>>> for month, group in g:
...     print(month)
...     print(group)
201401
20140101    0.1
20140102    0.2
dtype: float64
201402
20140201    0.3
20140202    0.4
dtype: float64
```

Or you could use pure python, although it is probably less efficient:

```
>>> groups = {}
>>> for t, a in zip(T, A):
...     month = t[:6]
...     groups.setdefault(month, []).append(a))
>>> for month, group in groups.items():
...     print(month)
...     print(group)
201402
[('20140201', 0.3), ('20140202', 0.4)]
201401
[('20140101', 0.1), ('20140102', 0.2)]
```

Comment: received error with pure python way: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: I don't get an error.  How are you creating the arrays?  Are they 1D or 2D? The `[[..]]` in your question suggests 2D, although the data is only 1D.  If you have 2D arrays, that would be the problem.